# Plot does not show at ax[0] in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I would like to create a side by side figure. I use matplotlib and Seaborn package for this; however, I just can't seem to fit a plot into the first box. Can anyone please tell me what part of my code is wrong?

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# create a test dataframe
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'genre': ['var1','var2'],
    'left plot': [1,3],
    'right plot': [2,4]})

# Making a figure with two subplots 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)   # 2 plots
fig.set_figheight(5)
fig.set_figwidth(8) 

# Plots
ax[0] = sns.barplot(x = 'left plot',y = 'genre',data = test)  # this is where the problem is
ax[1] = sns.barplot(x = 'right plot',y = 'genre',data = test) 
    
# show plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

The "Left plot" is missing; even though I already specified ax[0] for it. Please help :"(

Comment: You need `sns.barplot(..., ax=ax[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the ax when creating the sns plots should solve your problem :)

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# create a test dataframe
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'genre': ['var1','var2'],
    'left plot': [1,3],
    'right plot': [2,4]})

# Making a figure with two subplots 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)   # 2 plots
fig.set_figheight(5)
fig.set_figwidth(8) 

# Plots
sns.barplot(x = 'left plot',y = 'genre',data = test, ax=ax[0])  # this is where the problem is
sns.barplot(x = 'right plot',y = 'genre',data = test, ax=ax[1]) 

# show plot
plt.show()
```